# @Bindable usage with protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, ios17

Prior to iOS 17, I was used to creating SwiftUI views with a generic approach where a view is constrainted to one view model, and that ViewModel can be a protocol. This was very nice for testing and wrapping all the UI-related things to the ViewModels interface.

```
@MainActor
protocol CityQueryViewModelInterface: ObservableObject {
    var text: String { get set }
    func fetchWeather() async throws -> WeatherItem
}
```

```
struct CityQueryView<ViewModel: CityQueryViewModelInterface>: View {    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
}
```

However, when trying to achieve this in iOS 17 using the `Observable` macro with `@Bindable` and protocol, I am getting an error

```
protocol CityQueryViewModelInterface: Observable {
    var text: String { get set }
    func fetchWeather() async throws -> WeatherItem
}
```

```
@Observable
final class CityQueryViewModel: CityQueryViewModelInterface {
```

```
struct CityQueryView<ViewModel: CityQueryViewModelInterface>: View {
    @Bindable var viewModel: ViewModel
}
```

`'init(wrappedValue:)' is unavailable: The wrapped value must be an object that conforms to Observable`

Next to the Bindable annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says

> The wrapped value must be an ***object*** that conforms to Observable.

Notice the highlight on "object".

`Bindable` requires `Observable` and `AnyObject` so just add `AnyObject` to your `protocol`.

```
protocol CityQueryViewModelInterface: Observable, AnyObject {
    var text: String { get set }
    func fetchWeather() async throws -> WeatherItem
}
```