# Using @Bindable with a Observable type in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, observation

***Originally asked on Swift Forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/using-bindable-with-a-observable-type/70993***

I'm using SwiftUI environments in my app to hold a preferences object which is an @Observable object

But I want to be able to inject different instances of the preferences object for previews vs the production code so I've abstracted my production object in to a `Preferences` protocol and updated my Environment key's type to:

```swift
protocol Preferences { }

@Observable
final class MyPreferencesObject: Preferences { }

@Observable
final class MyPreviewsObject: Preferences { }


// Environment key

private struct PreferencesKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue : Preferences & Observable = MyPreferencesObject()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var preferences: Preferences & Observable {
        get { self[PreferencesKey.self] }
        set { self[PreferencesKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The compiler is happy with this until I go to use `@Bindable` in my code where the compiler explodes with a generic error,
eg:

```swift
@Environment(\.preferences) private var preferences

// ... code

@Bindable var preferences = preferences
```

If I change the environment object back to a conforming type eg:

```swift
@Observable
final class MyPreferencesObject() { }

private struct PreferencesKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue : MyPreferencesObject = MyPreferencesObject()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var preferences: MyPreferencesObject {
        get { self[PreferencesKey.self] }
        set { self[PreferencesKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then `@Bindable` is happy again and things compile.

Specifically the compiler errors with:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (Swift.org - Contributing)
> On the parent function the @Bindable is inside of

and with a

> Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code
> In the app target.

Is this a known issue/limitation? Or am I missing something here?

### Example code:

```swift
import Observation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(SomeProtocol.self) private var someThing
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var thing = someThing
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $thing.name)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environment(Actual(name: ""))
}

protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject, Observable {
    var name: String { get set }
}

@Observable
class Actual: SomeProtocol {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Example project here : https://github.com/adammcarter/observable-example/

Comment: Why do you need to use `@Binable` at all for an Environment object? Why not use `@Environment` again?

Comment: Without the `@Bindable` the environment object is passed as a get only property and so I can't mutate it, `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'preferences' is a get-only property`

Comment: You didn’t understand what I said. One of the main points with @Environment is that you don’t need to pass the to sub views, just declare the property again in the sub view, `@Environment(\.preferences) private var preferences`

Comment: Using EnvironmentKey for an Observable isn’t supported. If you turn on strict concurrency you will see a warning. static for a non-Sendable does not pass Swift6 checks. Apple is revealing more and more errors as we get closer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson apologies, I see what you mean now... I've tried this but it still creates the same issue as the environment object is readonly and I need to create a binding from one of the properties eg `preferences.myText` is a `String` so won't go in to the `Binding<String>` needed for a text field

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum - is there a workaround for this? Or some other design pattern I should be using?

Comment: I've just seen the big grey note in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject so will read more in to this!

Comment: Looks like I get the same issue using `@Environment(ObservablePreferences.self) private var preferences` where `ObservablePreferences = Preferences & Observable`

Comment: @Environment(ObservablePreferences.self)  Is correct but you need to refine the generic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794933/bindable-usage-with-protocols/77795039#77795039

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for the link but the issue is about using the protocol itself as the type in `Environment()` - when passing a concrete type it works but the protocol type (even with the constraint of AnyObject) doesn't work. I've updated the original question with a link to an example project

Comment: I doubt you’ll get help with a link SO questions should be all inclusive but if your goal is for the Environment to interpret generics at runtime it won’t work no matter what you do. You need a custom solution.